# build research and use it as an external package for research project

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I want to perform some research regarding quantization/sparsification, I would like to use run_experiment.py script as a template, to do so in a clean matter as research is not part of the pip package I was wondering if it is possible to build it myself and then reuse it as a dependency (as in run_experiment.py some functions from research are used). I am not sure however how to do it. I am not familiar with bazel. I was able to install it and run the script, that's all. Any guidance would be highly appreciated! Or if it's not possible it would be good to know as well! Thank you for any advice in this matter.

EDIT:
I built something using bazel and I have it in bazel-bin I don't know now however how to reuse it in my script, as if I just wanted to do it in a python manner 
`from research.compression import compression_process_adapter` 
or somehthing similar in my script

Answer (score 0):

[Using TFF for Federated Learning Research](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/tff_for_research.md) gives a rough introduction on suggestions for organizing the experiment conceptually.

From there, seeing how "run scripts" are setup in various sub-directories under [`tensorflow_federated/python/research/`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research) might be good examples. If there is an sub directory that is close to what you want to accomplish, forking/copying it might be a good place to start.

For instance, [`tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/experiments/emnist/run_experiments.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/experiments/emnist/run_experiments.py) might be a useful example for how to setup an experiment grid. This iteratively runs [`tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/experiments/emnist/train.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/experiments/emnist/train.py), which has an example of how to import libraries under the `research/` directory. Note that all of these uses bazel, and the depedencies for the imports are decalred in the [tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/experiments/emnist/BUILD](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/experiments/emnist/BUILD) file.

Finally, this script can be run with (from the git repo root directory):

```sh
bazel run -c opt tensorflow_federated/python/research/gans/experiments/emnist:run_experiments
```